# In my Jenkins shared library, why am I seemingly not executing my methods?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following shared-library structure

```
com/company/test/
                /ServiceBuilder.groovy
                /MonoBuilder.groovy
                /MicroServiceBuilder.groovy
```

Then in `src/com/test/builders`, I have these 3 files

```
#ServiceBuilder.groovy
package com.company.test

abstract class ServiceBuilder implements Serializable {
  protected String msg = null
  // Used by all sub-classes
  protected def printMsg() {
    println "${this.msg}"
  }
  // Implement in sub-classes
  protected def setMsg(final String msg) {
  }
}

#MicroserviceBuilder.groovy
package com.company.test

class MicroserviceBuilder extends ServiceBuilder {
  MicroserviceBuilder(){
    super()
  }
  def setMsg(final String msg) {
    println this.getClass()
    this.msg = "Mirco: $msg"
  }
}

#MonoServiceBuilder
package com.company.test

class MonoBuilder extends ServiceBuilder {
  MonoBuilder(){
    super()
  }
  def setMsg(final String msg) {
    println this.getClass()
    this.msg = "Mono: $msg"
  }
}
```

Here's is the Jenkinsfile cat use the above shared library

```
@Library("my-shared-lib@feature/test-shared-lib") _
import com.company.test.ServiceBuilder
import com.company.test.MonoBuilder
import com.company.test.MicroserviceBuilder

node("linux-ubuntu") {
  stage("Mono"){
    ServiceBuilder builder = new MonoBuilder()
    builder.setMsg("hello")
    builder.printMsg()
  }
  stage("Micro"){
    ServiceBuilder builder = new MicroserviceBuilder()
    builder.setMsg("hola")
    builder.printMsg()
  }
}
```

The code executes, but I don't see any of the expected `println` output. I expected

- class type to be printed when I call `object.setMsg(...)`
- `Mono: hello` for the `MonoService.printMsg()` call
- `Micro: hola` for the `Microservice.printMsg()` call

But just see in the Jenkins console

```
Running on linux-ubuntu-1 in /home/jenkins/workspace/Utilities/Playground/test-shared-lib
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Mono)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Micro)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

What am I missing? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by looking at [Why do I love Jenkins shared libraries?](https://medium.com/@adnn.selimovic/why-do-i-love-jenkins-shared-libraries-c9041ee64b93). Here are my 3 modified Groovy files, where I added a `jfile` attribute, which is the `this` pointer of the calling `Jenkinsfile`.

```
#ServiceBuilder.groovy
package com.company.test

abstract class ServiceBuilder implements Serializable {
  protected def jfile = null
  protected String msg = null
  protected def printMsg() {
    jfile.println "${this.getClass()}: ${this.msg}"
  }
  protected def setMsg(final String msg) {
  }
}

#MicroserviceBuilder.groovy
package com.company.test

class MicroserviceBuilder extends ServiceBuilder {
  MicroserviceBuilder(final def jfile){
    super()
    this.jfile = jfile
  }
  def setMsg(final String msg) {
    jfile.println this.getClass()
    this.msg = "Mirco: $msg"
  }
}

#MonoBuilder.groovy 
package com.zift.test

class MonoBuilder extends ServiceBuilder {
  MonoBuilder(final def jfile){
    super()
    this.jfile = jfile
  }
  def setMsg(final String msg) {
    jfile.println this.getClass()
    this.msg = "Mono: $msg"
  }
}
```

And here's the `Jenkinsfile`

```
@Library("zift-infrastructure@feature/test-share-lib") _
import com.company.test.ServiceBuilder
import com.company.test.MonoBuilder
import com.company.test.MicroserviceBuilder

node("linux-ubuntu") {
  stage("Mono"){
    ServiceBuilder builder = new MonoBuilder(this)
    builder.setMsg("hello")
    builder.printMsg()
  }
  stage("Micro"){
    ServiceBuilder builder = new MicroserviceBuilder(this)
    builder.setMsg("hola")
    builder.printMsg()
  }
}
```

The Jenkins console output now shows

```
Running on linux-ubuntu-2 in /home/jenkins/workspace/Utilities/Playground/test-shared-lib
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Mono)
[Pipeline] echo
class com.zift.test.MonoBuilder
[Pipeline] echo
class com.zift.test.MonoBuilder: Mono: hello
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Micro)
[Pipeline] echo
class com.zift.test.MicroserviceBuilder
[Pipeline] echo
class com.zift.test.MicroserviceBuilder: Mirco: hola
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

which is the expected output. But why did I have to do this, using the caller's `println` instead of being able to do it in the classes themselves?